# Delete multiple rows in MYSQL with info from python list

Tags: python, mysql, string, sql-delete

If list LL:

`LL = ['foo', bar', 'noo', 'boo',]`

is in a MySQL table, test in column ID with other ID's.

I could use the following to delete all rows with ID's in LL:

```
 csr.execute("""DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = "Foo"; """)
  csr.execute("""DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = "bar"; """)  
  csr.execute("""DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = "noo"; """)
  csr.execute("""DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = "boo"; """)
```

How could I do it programatically?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it with a single query:

```
id_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
query_string = "delete from test where id in (%s)" % ','.join(['?'] * len(id_list))
cursor.execute(query_string, id_list)
```

Since cursor.execute escapes strings when doing substitutions, this example is safe against SQL injections.

Comment: No, see how the query string in the answer says "where id in ..." not "where id = ..."

Comment: @user428862 "in ('abc', 'hjk', ... )" works in MySQL. It's preferred over "where id='abc' or id='hjk'". However my example contained a syntax error and numerical IDs. Try the updated version.

Comment: id_list = ['acb','def', ]  The SQL contains 0 parameter markers, but 2 parameters were supplied'

Comment: You need to construct the query_string variable as specified. It replaces each id with a %s.

Comment: print of query_str " delete from  test where id in (%s,%s)

Comment: That looks fine. Then use cursor.execute(query_str, id_list)

Comment: Is there a way to check string of 'query_str, id_list',    I checked manual input. this should work if I can escape the " that need for text in mysql. TIA

Comment: cursor.execute(string, list) performs variable expansion on the values in string based on their types. You don't need to escape quotes, just put %s into to the query string and it will be substituted by values taken in order from the list. I believe my example should work. The value from (query_string % id_list) will not be equal to the query produced by cursor.execute.

Comment: Oh! Sorry, I guess it's language blur. I fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

For MySQL you need to use `%s` instead of `?` as the parameter marker. And don't forget to commit.

```
product_list = [645, 64, 9785, 587]
query = "DELETE FROM products WHERE id IN (%s)" % ",".join(["%s"] * len(product_list))
cursor.execute(query, product_list)
connection.commit()
```

Answer (score 1):

String formatters - http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax

```
["""DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = "%s"; """ % x for x in LL]
```

and then run each of the SQL statements in the list.

Comment: It is of critical importance that `LL` contains only trusted items. If it contains data from untrusted sources and not properly escaped, SQL injection is possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
for item in LL:
    csr.execute("DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID = '%s'", item)
```

like that?

Comment: typo- `each` should be `item`.  fixed.

Comment: that bad example , u are executing many queries which lead to overloading your db

Answer (score 0):

Just convert the list into a string format with comma-separated and use a normal where clause with in condition.

```
id_list = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
id_list_string = "', '".join(id_list)
delete_query = "delete from test where id in ('" +id_list_string+"')"
dbconnection.execute(delete_query)
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain your answer.

Answer (score -2):

We can use one delete query and convert the list into tuple.

```
list_ids = ['foo', bar', 'noo', 'boo',]
delete_query = "DELETE FROM test.test WHERE ID=%s"
delete_records = tuple(list_ids)
cursor.executemany(delete_exec, delete_records)
```