# If value true but null not work

Tags: python, mysql

I made program is input number and delete data in mysql. but run program error then report `sql1` Syntax Error\i change true

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import mysql.connector

conn = mysql.connector.connect(host="",user="",passwd="",db="")
cursor = conn.cursor()

try:
        num = int(input("InputNumber 1-10 : "))
        if num <= 10:
                if num == null: //if null print false
                        sql1 = "SELECT user1 FROM dt WHERE user1 = '%d' " %(num)
                        cursor.execute(sql1)
                        data = cursor.fetchall()
                print(data[0])
                sqlde = "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 = '%d' " %(num)
                cursor.execute(sqlde, (num))
                print "DELETE SUCESS"
                conn.commit()
        else:
                print "Data Empty"
except:
        conn.rollback()

conn.close()
```

Comment: Always show full error message. You have wrong indentions. Don't use `%` to create query - it can be insecure - use `execute(..., arguments)`.

Comment: you forgot last `)` in `int(input(...))`

Comment: OHHHHHHHH ! thank you :D bad forgot

Comment: `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: I repeat: Always show full error message. There is not only message but also line with problem, etc. And put error in question.

Comment: this error mean you have wrong indentions - for example:. `try` needs inside lines with indentions  but you have without indentions.

Answer (score 2):

num =   int(input("InputNumber: ")`)`  <- don't forguet to close it

I'm not sure about the `%i`, I always see using `%d` for Integer and `%s` to strings

But, you also have one problem into your query, [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

So to avoid this, try something like this

```
sql1 = "DELETE FROM dt WHERE user1 = ?"
                try:
                        cursor.execute(sql1, (num))
                        print "DELETE SUCECC"
                        conn.commit()
                except:
                        conn.rollback()
                        print "ERROR DELETE"
```

you can check about [question mark here](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) or [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement#Parameterized_statements) and understand why you should bind your values

Comment: what a `IndentationError: expected an indented block`

Comment: This is because you are mixing Spaces and tabs. Decide just one kind of identation and use-it, or just spaces, or just tabs, my recomendation use just spaces. Most editors have an option for automatically converting tabs to spaces. If your editor has this option, turn it on

Comment: And i want to delete multi row together i can ?

Comment: check this question: 
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26347412/drop-multiple-columns-pandas
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5955841/delete-multiple-rows-in-mysql-with-info-from-python-list

Comment: @UsuchaBootsarakam, always pay attention to your indentation in python - https://www.quora.com/What-does-indentation-mean-in-python